# Push notifications on new hockeyapp builds for Android?

Tags: android, hockeyapp

I'm running beta distribution through hockeyapp and versions are going and sending emails but I'm looking for a way to enable a push notification. The devices we're testing with aren't setup for email so after seeing the mail, testers still need to open the app and find the new build. I was hoping to streamline that process to one click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mandatory update feature available in Hockey app.

1. Go To App -> Manage Version -> Status

[image: Status Screen]

2. Scroll down to `Mandatory Update` feature at bottom
   [image: Mandatory Update]
3. And set it to enabled.

Based on their description:

> **Update alpha/beta apps:** The app will check with HockeyApp if a new version for your alpha/beta build is available. **If yes, it will show a dialog to users and let them see the release notes, the version history and start the installation process right away**. You can even force the installation of certain updates.

If you want to customize this behavior and display notification instead of popup you can do so by using `net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateManagerListener`

While registering for update receiver you can do following:
`UpdateManager.register(context, APP_ID, new MyCustomUpdateManagerListener());`

In your listener, you can display the notification using notification API. You can find details [here](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk#updatedistribution-advanced)

**Note:** Its mandatory to have Hockey App SDK to be integrated in order to streamline your process. More information regarding this integration is available [here](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk#updatedistribution)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I wanted. Just a notification from hockeyapp on the device to remind you to download the new version. I don't want to push the version until the tester is ready. E-mail notification is ok, but they won't have email on the test device so it's still a multi-step process.